# Jquery remove class active when click happen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working with the next html structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">
        <small>Ubicacion</small>
        <a class="item-content" href="#">
        <i class="item-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Ubicaciones</span>
        <i class="down fas fa-sort-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu ubicaciones">
            <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code is a part of the next sidebar

[image: SIDEBAR]

I have this Jquery code:

```
$('.menu .item').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.item-content .down').toggleClass('active')
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active')
})
```

With this code I just get the element with the class down that is the arrow icon and I add the class active to rotate arrow up. and I make the same with the element with the class sub-menu I add class active to show it

Also I have this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.sub-item', function (evemt) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('Hola!')
})
```

With this code I want to get the text inside sub-item element but  when I make click in any alement with the class sub-item the class active is remove from my elements down and sub-menu and sub-menu is hidde and I don't want this I tried using preventDefault but it don't work

Can someone tell me what is my error?

Comment: you've a typo in your jquery on click event , it should be event not evemt

Comment: thanks! I change it but I have the same problem

Comment: then, i think you may need to set active class on them again in this fucntion

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of single event handler, like this :

```js
$('.menu .item').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass('sub-item')) {
    console.log('Hola!')
  } else {
    $(this).find('.item-content .down').toggleClass('active')
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('active')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <small>Ubicacion</small>
    <a class="item-content" href="#">
      <i class="item-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Ubicaciones</span>
      <i class="down fas fa-sort-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu ubicaciones">
      <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```